# SonataMediaBundle - How to use custom file input

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I have a kind of scavenger hunt project in which I am using AngularJS to manage the different questions it may contain. These questions are of different types. Therefore, some may include a file input and some may not. In this project, I am also using Symfony and SonataMediaBundle to manage my files and my images.

Since my html model (mostly my forms) can change depending on the actions of the user, I cannot use Symfony's built-in tool to produce forms. Therefore, all my forms are custom made. This gives me a problem with SonataMediaBundle, when I want some files to be uploaded. If a user selects a file, this file will be sent via POST to a method in the controller, when the form gets sent. Therefore, I want to send this received file to SonataMediaBundle so that it can manage it, but I haven't found anywhere in the documentation how to do such a thing.

Theoretically, it is really simple. In my controller, when I get a file input, I want to let SonataMedia manage the upload (that is the copy to the proper location, etc...) and I have no clue on how I should do that.

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at: https://gist.github.com/romaricdrigon/6291435. This allows you to use the Symfony way of building forms in combination with AngularJS. You can build the form any way you like and return it from the back-end into your SPA.

Answer (score 8):

Using symfony2 and not utilizing its benefits you are doing a big mistake you should built your app properly but as far as concerned to your question nothing is bounded by symfony but its on your own how you use it.You can get the sonata media manager service from the container  and you have to manually set the all the required setters for the media manager and you have to manually work for the validations like file size ,file mimetype etc. Below is the demo how you can store the file in the sonata media bundle

```
/* Before class use these*/
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media;

public function uploadAction()
{

$file = $this->get('request')->files->get('filefieldname');

    if (!$file instanceof UploadedFile || !$file->isValid()) {
        return new Response(json_encode(array(
            'event' => 'uploader:error',
            'data'  => array(
                'message' => 'Missing file.',
            ),
        )));
    }

/* validate max min size for the file */
/* validate mime type for the file */
/* Get sonata media manager service from container    */ 
$mediaManager = $this->container->get('sonata.media.manager.media');
/* create new instance of sonata media class in my case entity is located at 
* Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media 
*/
$media = new Media();
$media->setBinaryContent($file);
$media->setContext('default'); 
$ImagemimeTypes = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png');
$FilemimeTypes = array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
    'application/msword', 'application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf');
if (in_array($file->getMimeType(), $FilemimeTypes)) {
    $media->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.file');
}
if (in_array($file->getMimeType(), $ImagemimeTypes)) {
    $media->setProviderName('sonata.media.provider.image');
}
 /*If you have other providers in your app like vimeo /dailymotion etc
 then do set here i have shown you the demo for adding image/file in sonata media */
/*other setters if you want to set like enabled/disable etc*/
 $mediaManager->save($media);
// end function
}
```

But once again there will be alot of rework you have to do which symfony already provides you the ease for

Answer (score 1):

The Bundle is there to close exactly this gap between Symfony and SonataMedia. SonataMedia is made for raw PHP, while the SonataMediaBundle attaches Symfony interfaces to SonataMedia; you're rewriting large part of the Bundle's functionality. To get a good example of how it is done right, look at the Bundle's code ;)

Sorry if the next suggestion is something you considered thoroughly, I just cannot be certain based on the limited information in the question. Symfony forms are highly flexible and provide a lot of critical functionality that you should not try to re-implement yourself (like CSRF-tokens). Most problems have a good solution with the form system. If a form is metamorphic (has many constellation of fields, based on UI interaction) and cannot be handled by multiple form types, you still have options. If you can set a GET parameter indicating which type of form is currently being sent then you can pass that to the FormBuilder. You may even choose to build a single big form for the whole application, which contain every field you ever use - that's a bit of a waste but still better than trying to wire posting+sonata together. The most hurt the first version does are some extra bytes and empty field. The least hurt you try could do is introduce serious security leaks.

Comment: I could do what you mention, if it wasn't for this. I can have up to 20 questions and each question can be of different types (I have 10 different type of questions). Therefore, I would have to pass to my page, 200 hundred different forms so that I can manage all the different possibilities and this seems not like a good option...

Comment: If you say you have 10 types I understand it as having 10 variations for fields. If every question can have any type of the form, then I see two steps. 1) Create one FormType class that builds so many field that it can contain any of the 10 types (e.g. if there is a text and a radio for type1 and a text and 3 checkboxes for type2, then you build a form with a text, a radio and 3 checkboxes). 2) Get a formbuilder, and for each question $builder->add() one instance of this FormType (its constructor parameters can take care of individual 'choices' lists and which fields really need adding.

Comment: If you still don't feel like this would easily solve the problem then please edit the question so that we see at least 2-3 of the 10 question types, and 2-3 of the 20 questions, preferably in some combination, so we can figure out why this poses a much bigger challenge than it should.