# Include a media type in an Entity from Sonata Admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-media-bundle

I'm making an Entity which is called Article, it should have some text, a video and a couple of images. For the latter I'm doing it by allowing the user to create a media and then include the images there, now for the question... how do I relate that media to the article? Do I have a "media list picker" to choose from?

Comment: It might give you an [*idea*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22081957/sonatamediabundle-how-to-use-custom-file-input/22254206#22254206)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include Sonata MediaBundle in the Admin Bundle, you'll need to add for example an Image field to your Article entity.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Gallery")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $image;
```

And then refer to it in your ArclicleAdmin :

```
->add('image', 'sonata_type_model_list', array('required' => false))
```